# why the method must be in Parent also if at the end it will print the content of Child

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, parent-child

Parent p = new Child();
Why can't I use print() method in the Parent without overriding it in Child?

```
public class OverridingMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();        
        // why this does not work
        p.print();
    }
}
 
class Parent{
    /*
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Parent Method");
    }
    */
}
 
class Child extends Parent{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Child Method");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

Here, we declare a variable called `p`. Its value is `new Child()`. As far as *this particular* line of code is concerned, we're making a `Child` instance. However, you've assigned it to a variable of type `Parent`. This is fine; it's called upcasting and it's a fundamental part of inheritance-based polymorphism.

However, because you've done that, the compiler recognizes that `p` is of type `Parent`. On all subsequent lines of code, Java has forgotten that `p` is *actually* a `Child` and only assumes that it's a `Parent`, since that's what you told it to assume. If `Parent` doesn't know how to `print`, then we can't `print` it, because we told Java to forget that we have that functionality. If `Parent` *does* know how to `print`, then we can `print` it. *How* we print it is irrelevant; subclasses are free to override that unless the method is `final`. All that matters is that we *can*.

Now, Java provides us backdoors into this mechanism. In theory, once we write

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

after this line, we should *never* be able to realize that `p` is a `Child` again. We told Java to treat it like any other `Parent`. Generally, that's good. If you say something is a `Parent`, you should treat it like one. If you want a `Child`, you should've asked for a `Child`. If we *really* need to, we can "cheat" the type system and see what's really in the box.

```
if (p instanceof Child) {
  Child c = (Child)p;
  ...
}
```

Now we've "recovered" the original child. Code that makes frequent use of the above runtime checks if often a sign of a poorly-designed codebase.